# Mapping between IEDriverServer and versions of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Please, I have to test IEDriverServer under (IE8->IE11) on my tests automated with Java Selenium Webdriver. I downloaded from version 2.41 to 2.45 of IEDriverServer and I launch the test and every time the navigator IE started and checked the URL but I don't know if webdriver launch the IE wich installed on my PC or another that matchs with the version of IEDriverServer ?
Please, Can you give me yours responses.
Thanks in Advance,

Best Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your attention but It is another question

Answer (score 0):

IEDriver does not launch a different Internet Explorer than what is installed on your computer.  IEDriver does not include a copy of Internet Explorer, but rather just launches whatever version of Internet Explorer is currently installed.

The biggest difference between the different versions of IEDriver is the compatibility with different IE versions.

If you need to test multiple different Internet Explorer versions, I would suggest using a service such as [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) or [Modern.IE](https://www.modern.ie/en-us), since you can only have one version of Internet Explorer installed on your machine at a time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what isn't open source?  your question doesn't really make sense in this context.